# Is there any way to use a background for the hint in the TextInputLayout?

Tags: android

I need the hint to have this form when the input is disabled:

[image: TextInputLayout]

That is what I have achieved so far:

[image: TextInputLayout]

I tried to add a background using HintTextAppearance in the style, but it was not applied.

```
<style name="HintAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_material_form</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
</style>


<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/HintAppearance">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="value" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want a minor padding?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti yes, a minor padding and rounded corners, but the minor padding is the priority.

Comment: No way with the current library